# 'Wrap' widget - items alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a way to align `Wrap` widget items in all lines except the last with `spaceAround` and the last one with `start`? Is there another way to do it? Number of rows and columns should not be fixed - it depends on device width and height.

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext bc) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          spacing: 10.0,
          alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
             //items
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
```

See screenshot how it actually looks like. I need the last row to have the same spacing as the others and start from the left.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to achieve this with Wrap widget, but similar effect produce GridView with `extent` constructor:

```
        GridView.extent(
          children: List.generate(10, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.star_border,
                size: 100.0,
              ),
            );
          }),
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 150.0,
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the item is known, it can be achieved in this way:

```
const itemCount = 10;
const itemSize = 100.0;
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, c) {
    const spacing = 0.0;

    final columnCount =
        ((c.maxWidth + spacing) / (itemSize + spacing)).floor();
    final rowCount = (itemCount / columnCount).ceil();
    final maxLength = columnCount * rowCount;

    return Wrap(
      spacing: spacing,
      children: List.generate(
        math.max(itemCount, maxLength),
        (index) => index < itemCount
            ? _buildItem(context, index)
            : const SizedBox(width: itemSize, height: itemSize),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```